# Replacing a line in text file while in a for loop {python}

Tags: python, updating, read-write

having trouble trying to replace a line in a text file with new updated info.
The aim is to record the attendance of specific students in a given course or module. A text file is already created for each course with students recorded already. The script takes in input from the user and is supposed to update the text file.

```
def record_attendence():
    print("Module Record System - Attendance - Choose a Module")
    print("-"*50)
    print("SOFT_6017")
    print("SOFT_6018")
    module = int(input())
    if module == 1:
        filename = "SOFT_6017.txt"
        with open(filename) as connection:
            for line in connection.readlines():
                i = 1
                print(f"Student #{i}: {line.split(':')[0]} ")
                print("present")
                print("absent")
                attendence = int(input())
                if attendence == 1:
                    og_line = (line.split(':'))
                    og_line[1] = str(int(og_line[1]) + 1)
                    og_line = ":".join(og_line)
                    print(og_line)


def main():
    record_attendence()

main()
```

The text file looks like this

```
Micheal Martin:0:0
Bob Wade:0:0
Sarah Norton:0:0
```

I've been looking online for numerous ways to get this done but nothing I try works, I've tried the replace function but it didnt work,

I'm new to python so any advice would be appreciated

edit:
right now, nothing should be written to the file, the print(og_line) is just there because I was checking if I converted the list back into a string properly.

the input would look something like

### Module Record System - Attendance - Choose a Module

SOFT_6017

SOFT_6018

1

Student #1: Micheal Martin

present

absent

1

1 represents being present,

the specific line in the text file about micheal martin should change from
Micheal Martin:0:0
to
Michael Martin:1:0

for calcification, the same thing should be happening if absent is choosen as well, just adjusted so the second 0 would change instead of the first

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you expect along with the sample input?

Comment: Split the line once, and store the tokens.

Comment: If you're going to use a flat file (which is an incredibly poor design) then you'll need to read the entire content into memory, make your changes (in memory) then, when all changes have been made, re-write the entire file. Apart from the name (obviously), what do the two numbers mean (0:0)?

Comment: @AnukaKuruppuarachchi what would you expect as the output?

Answer (score 0):

You could first load the records, update them, and finally write them all back:

```py
def load_record(option):
  match option:
    case 1:
      return "SOFT_6017.txt"
    case 2:
      return "SOFT_6018.txt"

def record_attendence():
  records = []

  print("Module Record System - Attendance - Choose a Module")
  print("-"*50)
  print("1. SOFT_6017")
  print("2. SOFT_6018")
  module = load_record(int(input()))
  
  # Load
  if module is not None:
    with open(module, 'r') as connection:
      records = [line.strip().split(':') for line in connection.readlines()]
  
  # Loop through all records
  for i, record in enumerate(records):
    print(f"Student #{i + 1}: {record[0]}")
    print("1. Present")
    print("2. Absent")
    choice = int(input())
    
    # Update
    if choice >= 1 and choice <= 2:
      record[choice] = str(int(record[choice]) + 1)
  
  # Overwrite
  with open(module, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines([f"{':'.join(record)}\n" for record in records])


def main():
  record_attendence()

main()
```